# Number of Witnesses Against the Accused Boy in '12 Angry Men'

Tags: 12-angry-men

In the film "12 Angry Men," how many people testified against the boy who was accused in total?

Comment: Please refrain from adding the `analysis` tag to each and every unrelated question.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if there are other 'character' witnesses or the like, but there are two discussed eye-witnesses that testify in the case:

- One who claims to have seen the murder taking place, through the window
  and the windows of a passing train
- A neighbor who testifies to a verbal threat to kill the father, who hears
  the ruckus from the room, and the defendant running down the stairs of the
  apartment

> #8 Juror (smiling)
>
> *I kept putting myself in the boy's place. I would have asked for another lawyer, I think. I mean, if I was on trial for my life I'd
> want my lawyer to tear the prosecution witnesses to shreds, or at
> least to try. Look, there was one alleged, eye-witness to this
> killing. Someone else claims he heard, the killing and then saw the
> boy running out afterward. **There was a lot of circumstantial evidence,
> but actually those two witnesses were the entire case for the
> prosecution. We're dealing with a human life here. Supposing they were
> wrong?***
>
> <sub><sup>[12 Angry Men - Script](https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/12AngryMen.pdf)</sup></sub>